# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Point must be in 'lat, lon' or 'x y' format:

Tags: apache, solr

I was getting this error while runnning the solr server

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Point must be in 'lat, lon' or 'x y' format:

```
<entity name="address" query="SELECT id,eatery_city, eatery_country,eatery_address1 || ', ' || eatery_locality || ', ' || eatery_city || ', ' || eatery_state as address ,lat, lng FROM eatery_address_details where id = (select eatery_address_details from eatery where id = '${eatery.id}')">
            <field column="eatery_country" name="country"/>
            <field column="eatery_city" name="city"/>
            <field column="address" name="address"/>
            <field column="lat" name="lat"/>
            <field column="lng" name="lng"/>
        </entity>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says - anything mapped into a location field must be in the format of "latitude,longitude" or "latitude longitude". You select the fields as separate columns. Concat them into one single value using `CONCAT` in your SQL statement, and populate the single field with the value (instead of two fields as you're doing now) and you should be good to go.